# Pycharm - remote server with proxy

Tags: ssh, pycharm

I know how to connect with Pycharm to a remote server (in order to run on a GPU),  but how can I connect to a remote server with a proxy ssh?

Comment: PyCharm supports OpenSSH config (not on Windows) so `ProxyJump` in `~/.ssh/config` should do the trick, e.g. https://github.com/tejksat/ssh-behind-bastion-playback/blob/master/.ssh/config